# What should I do in Android, if I MUST do very heavy UI manipulation?

Tags: android, multithreading

Android advises always that long operations should be done on background threads. However, the background threads are not allowed to manipulate the UI.

What I'm trying to accomplish is building a UI from an XML definition. I already parse the XML on a background thread, but adding the views, and settings their attributes is really not possible on that thread.

Is there anything I can do to make the app keep responsive while the remaining UI manipulation tasks are done?

**Note:** I haven't tested how much time this manipulation takes. I just assume it is much, because a lot of control is going to be added, and a lot of property is going to be set.

**Edit:** I've already managed to do the parsing in the background, so I know how to create threads, communicate between them. I'm curious if can do anything to have the UI be more responsive, when I'm FORCED to run many things on the UI thread.

Comment: Consider using a ListView if possible.

Comment: @FD_ ListView is unfortunately not possible to be used, because the customer wants absolute positioning of the controls. Anyway, would that improve performance/responsiveness?

Comment: Wait, absolute positioning and thousands of controls? Will there even be enough space on-screen for this many controls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what kind of UI you are trying to build, but it really shouldn't take all that much time. Try it first, optimize later.

If performance really turns out to be a problem, and your UI is modular in any way, try to use ListViews or GridViews to compose it. They will only build the Views needed to fill the screen, and recycle them to build new components as you are scrolling down and up the screen.

Comment: I have to do absolute positioning of the Views. I'll look into the source of ListView to see if I can accomplish the same with absolute positioning.

Answer (score 2):

You can use two things :-

1. Worker Threads
2. AsyncTask

They both are capable of updating the UI from a different thread.
Both are explained in this link [Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html)

Comment: It is impossible to update the UI from a different thread. When you want to update from a different thread, you must use `runOnUiThread`, which does what it says: runs the runnable on the **UI thread**.
I didn't see that in your answer explicitly, but are you saying that using another thread to jump back to the UI thread makes the process faster, or more responsive?

Comment: This is a paragraph from the link i shared :- To fix this problem, Android offers several ways to access the UI thread from other threads. Here is a list of methods that can help:

Activity.runOnUiThread(Runnable)
View.post(Runnable)
View.postDelayed(Runnable, long)

Comment: You can manipulate the update of UI timings by using View.postDelayed(Runnable, long) as per your need.

Comment: I already know of how to do minor changes to the UI. My question is that if I must do very heavy manipulation, is there anything I can alter on the already known techniques, to make the UI more responsive. If I say in the runnable passed in these functions Thread.sleep(3000), the UI is frozen for 3 seconds. So, are you saying that if I split the UI creation to the most/smallest runnable possible, that would mean so minor changes, that even if you have thousands of posted runnables to the UI thread, the UI thread keeps responsive?

Comment: I am not sure how many views you are talking about. Please do not use sleep while updating the UI. Divide the work in smaller worker threads and for updating the images use AsyncTask

Comment: Sleep is only mentioned to show that if something time consuming is happening on UI thread, it doesn't matter if it's called from a background thread or not. See ivagarz's answer, he got what I'm asking.

Comment: He is right. If similar group of views are to be repeated then Listview is the best solution

Answer (score 1):

The most flexible solution, I think, would be Handlers: 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html